# Logarithm compact definition question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Hi I understand the following text, but have questions on the part after it:

[image: A]

I'm confused how applying the compact definition below yields $b^{log_b(xy)} = xy$.  How does $xy$ get multiplied as the argument to $log_b$?

[image: B]

Finally, it's my understanding that multiplying two expressions corresponds to adding their logarithms?  I see the last line expresses this, however the result is still $log_b(xy)$ and not $xy$.

Appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compact definition says, $s ^ {\log_s r} = r$

Take $r = xy$, $s = b$